# How to get the view instance from IMvxAndroidViewPresenter in xamarin android using mvvmcross

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

How to get the view from viewpresenter.

```
var viewpresenter = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidViewPresenter>();
viewpresenter.Show(new MvxViewModelRequest(typeof(IVP), null, null, null));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to do but from your code you want to perform a navigation. In such case you should use the [Navigation service](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/navigation) (requires Mvx >= 5, otherwise use `ShowViewModel` from your `ViewModel/MvxNavigatingObject`) and use it like this:

```
var navigationService = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxNavigationService>();
await navigationService.Navigate<MyViewModel>();
```

If you want a custom navigation just call

`await navigationService.ChangePresentation(new MyCustomPresentationHint());`

and in your custom presenter override `ChangePresentation(MvxPresentationHint hint)` to add your custom presentation logic.

The [Presenter](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/view-presenters) is not there to resolve it and use it directly but through the navigation service.

[Here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/be4dfea1099a053d0ad850c8b82767624784ca1d/MvvmCross/Platforms/Android/Presenters/MvxAndroidViewPresenter.cs) is the source code of the Android Presenter from where you can see that you cannot get the current view directly. If you would like to know which is your current Activity you could use

`var currentActivity = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity;`

HIH